# regex for match line

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

we can use `.*` to match a line from regex. but I need something else similar to this. because intellij grammar kit doesn't support for .*

Comment: Did you enable regex search? Or does the place where you use the pattern support regex at all? You mean, you are working with [this plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/Grammar-Kit)? Please add more details.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew IntelliJ certainly supports full regex searching of source code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Regex in search.
Then you can search new line using: \n

[image: Search box picture]

Answer (score 0):

Use `[^\n]*` to match a whole line without using `.` character